# how to refresh the ListView in android when data i appended to ListView

Tags: android, web-services, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have made a ListView and made a custom adapter for it,I am calling two Asynctask one for getting all messages from webservice and another is for reply of the message,I want to append the replied message to the ListView. Currently i am not getting it right way. My code is as below:

**main.java**

```
import com.epe.yehki.adapter.ChatAdapter;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.BackendAPIService;

import com.epe.yehki.uc.Header;
import com.epe.yehki.uc.Menu;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Pref;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Utils;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class ChatHistoryActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONArray msgArry;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    private ChatAdapter chatContent;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> msgList;
    ListView lv;
    JSONArray msgs = null;
    String pro_id, pro_name, pro_img, grup_id, sender_id, cust_id;
    TextView tv_switch;
    public boolean flag = false;
    Header header;
    Menu menu;
    Intent in;
    Button reply;
    RelativeLayout rl_reply;
    EditText et_reply;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_history);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        tv_switch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_switch);
        header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.header_msg);
        menu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menu_msg);
        reply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reply);
        rl_reply = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_reply);
        rl_reply.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_reply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_reply);
        menu.setSelectedTab(3);
        header.title.setText("Conversation");
        msgList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        pro_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
        sender_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
        grup_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_GROUP_ID);
        cust_id = Pref.getValue(ChatHistoryActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");

        /* new GetChatHistory().execute(); */

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                rl_reply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        });
        // message reply ...!!Chat api(conversation)
        reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DoReply().execute();
                // new GetChatHistory().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new GetChatHistory().execute();
    }

    private class GetChatHistory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatHistoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String query = Const.API_CHAT_HISTORY;
            url = "?customer_id=" + cust_id + "&group_id=" + grup_id + "&sender_id=" + sender_id + "&product_id=" + pro_id;
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            url = query + url;
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::My MESSGES URL::::::::::::::" + url);

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    msgArry = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    if (msgArry != null && msgArry.length() != 0) {
                        // looping through All Contacts

                        System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + msgArry.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < msgArry.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = msgArry.getJSONObject(i);

                            String custID = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID);
                            String custName = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME);
                            String proID = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                            String email = c.getString(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_EMAIL);
                            String photo = Const.API_HOST + "/" + c.getString(Const.TAG_PHOTO);
                            String msg_body = c.getString(Const.TAG_MESSAGE_BODY);
                            HashMap<String, String> message = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_ID, custID);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_NAME, custName);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proID);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, email);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_PHOTO, photo);
                            message.put(Const.TAG_MESSAGE_BODY, msg_body);

                            msgList.add(message);

                        }
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "No messgaes found", "yehki", "Ok");
                                msgList.clear();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("::::::::::::inside post:::::::::::");
            chatContent = new ChatAdapter(ChatHistoryActivity.this, msgList);
            chatContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(chatContent);

        }
    }

    /*
     * GET CONVERSATION LIST.........REPLY
     */
    private class DoReply extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatHistoryActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            String query = Const.API_MESSAGE_REPLY;
            url = "?customer_id=" + cust_id + "&group_id=" + grup_id + "&receiver_id=" + sender_id + "&product_id=" + pro_id + "&message=" + et_reply.getText().toString().trim();
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            url = query + url;
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::My MESSGES URL::::::::::::::" + url);

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::get chat history called:::::::::::::;;");
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    if (jsonObj.getString("status").equals("sucess")) {
                        // et_reply.setText("");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // et_reply.setText("");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatHistoryActivity.this, "Message has not been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("::::::::::::inside post:::::::::::");
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();

            chatContent = new ChatAdapter(ChatHistoryActivity.this, msgList);
            chatContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(chatContent);
            new GetChatHistory().execute();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you tried calling  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: ya i have already added it in my code.

Comment: Do not initiate your list adapter in onPostexecuted() method, instead of doing this, initiate it in onCreate method with empty list. Now when ever your getting the records just do following steps: 1) If you want to refresh the whole list : `listObject.clearAll(); listObject.addAll(Async returned list); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` 2) If you want to append the returned list to the listview : `listObject.addAll(Async returned list); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: i have changed the place of that code..and its working..:) thanks

Comment: @SpringBreaker-thank you bro..its working